# Creating a global counter on a Windows Form to count button presses

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli

This seems a very simple problem but for the life of me (i'm fairly new to Coding) I can't find the answer.

The basics are thus, I have a listbox, named listbox1, that I populate with various entries by pressing 1 of several buttons (each button having a set "value" to add to the list) but I want each element in the list to be incremented. E.G:

1. Object Z
2. Object F
3. Object W

So on and so forth. But all I have managed so far is to get a count on each individual button, meaning the count only increments for the same button, not all.
E.G:

1. Steadfast Boots
2. Ragefire Boots
3. Ragefire Boots
4. Steadfast Boots

Picture to show what i get in the listbox:
[Picture of the programme](http://i632.photobucket.com/albums/uu49/Jamy981/BDL-Glacorssnippet.png)

So pressing the button on the right adds an entry to the listbox/

```
private: System::Void btn_steadfast_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
     {
        static int i = 1;
        this->listBox1->Items->Add(i + ". Steadfast Boots ");
        i++;

private: System::Void btn_ragefire_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        static int i = 0;
        this->listBox1->Items->Add(i + ". Ragefire Boots ");
        i++;
     }
```

I believe I need a global Counter that each button refers to when pressed, just not sure how to go about it.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Regards Jamie

---

Extra Info

---

This is the code i tried (commented out is what i attempted to put in, whilst also removing the obsolete info such as the use of "i" and tried changing the "Form1" to BDLGlacors to represent the form name to no avail as this is the second form in the programme ):

```
#pragma endregion
private: System::Void BDLGlacors_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         }
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

             MessageBox::Show("Return to Menu?");
             BDLGlacors::Close();
         }
private: System::Void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         }
/*public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form{
private:
    int buttonPressCount;

public:
    Form1()
    {
        buttonPressCount = 0;

    }*/
private: System::Void btn_steadfast_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
     {
        static int i = 1;
        this->listBox1->Items->Add(/*buttonPressCount*/ i + ". Steadfast Boots ");
        //buttonPressCount++;
        i++;            
     }

private: System::Void btn_ragefire_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
     {
        static int i = 1;
        this->listBox1->Items->Add(/*buttonPressCount*/i + ". Ragefire Boots ");
        //buttonPressCount++;
        i++;
     }
```

Apologies for the long edit.

Comment: This is not a C++ question. I've retagged as seems appropriate to me - feel free to change it if I made an error.

Comment: Thank you for that, wasn't sure what tags to put.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand, but maybe you want the count as a field:

```
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
private:
    int buttonPressCount;

public:
    Form1()
    {
        buttonPressCount = 0;
        // ...
    }

private: System::Void btn_steadfast_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
    {
        this->listBox1->Items->Add(buttonPressCount + ". Steadfast Boots ");
        buttonPressCount++;

private: System::Void btn_ragefire_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        this->listBox1->Items->Add(buttonPressCount + ". Ragefire Boots ");
        buttonPressCount++;
     }
};
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your response.
However, I couldn't seem to manage fitting this into my code. I also assume that by "maybe you want the count as a field" your suggesting a variable for the count to be stored in?
Which seems to be what you are aiming for.

Comment: In your example, the "i" variable in each method is a different variable (plus, if there are several instances of the class, each method will access and update the same variable as the corresponding method in other instances, because the variable is static). In my example, the two methods will be accessing and updating the same variable, because it's an instance field in the class. And if there are several instances of the class, the field will be different for each instance. Again I'm not sure it's what you want, but your description of the problem seemed unclear to me.

Comment: Have updated my initial post with more information, and exactly what i tried.

Comment: I am also aware that the "i" variable is only local to the relevant button, which is what i'm trying to get around, but that was all i had that was working.

Comment: I see now that what I described is exactly what you want. I just didn't know what class the methods **btn_steadfast_Click** and **btn_ragefire_Click** belonged to. Just put **buttonPressCount** inside the class where those methods are (is it **BDLGlacors**?).

Comment: Another way is to just get the count of items in the list and use it like this:
`this->listBox1->Items->Add(this->listBox1->Items->Count + ". Ragefire Boots ");`

Comment: OMG! Both of these answers work amazingly well, not sure which one i will use but Thank you very much for your time and effor to understand my ramblings XD